# to check given number is even or not

Tags: python

i am beginner in python i am writing a code which return output even if input number is even else return odd for that i am using def function but its not giving desired output it show nothing. can any one help me to print output?

here is code i have written

```
number=int(input("num: "))

def is_even(number):
    """
    this is function
    check number is even or odd
    """
    if number%2==0:
        return "Even"
    else:
        return "Odd"

is_even(number)
```

Comment: Did you just forget to *print* the output?

Comment: Not that I would never expext a function called is_foo to return a string. I would expect it to return a boolean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works well. You just have to use your print statement to print your output i.e `print(is_even(number))`

You can also use one line of code in your function like this:

```
number = int(input("num: "))

def is_even(number):
    """
    this function checks whether
    a number is even or odd.
    """
    return ("Even" if number%2 == 0 else "Odd")

print(is_even(number))
```

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are missing is a print statement.

```
print(is_even(number))
```

should give the desired result.